# Most mouse and keyboard inputs stopped working in Blender 2.80. How can this be fixed?

Tags: interface

I have had this issue previously and I have it again. Most inputs in Blender stopped working. I can't select objects or click most buttons and keyboard shortcuts aren't working either, neither does touch or pen on the tablet. I downloaded the newest release candidate and the issue is still there. I reset settings to factory settings and the issue still persists. What do i do? 
I have tried turning the computer off and on again.

Windows 10, 64 bit Blender 2.8 RC3

Solved it. Resetting to factory settings didn't help, deleting the 2.8 folder from appdata did.

Comment: Step 1) Makes sure that your hardware fulfills the minimum requirements https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ Step 2) If it does, update your graphics driver Step 3) If the problem persists it's either a bug or a problem with your operating system/hardware. You could report it in the official bug tracker but the developers will need a detailed description and steps to reproduce the issue reliably.

Comment: yes, minimum requirements are fulfilled. graphics drivers are up to date. it can't be a bug because the issue appeared on its own after using the version of blender without troubles for weeks.

Comment: Recent OS updates that may have introduced problems?

Comment: not as far as i know

Comment: You could check the Windows Event Viewer for error messages. Hard to diagnose with the given information.

Comment: Please do not change the title to "SOLVED" and do not include your answer in the question. Instead post the answer you found as an answer.

Comment: While you may have found how to get back to normal, you should expect to get stuck again unless you learn what happened. In the topmost edit menu there is an option to Lock Object Modes. This makes it hard to select another object in some modes, such as in pose mode you need to go back to object mode to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rig in the scene, make sure you aren't in "pose" mode. If in pose mode you can't select the mesh just by clicking on it. You must switch to object mode first.